Langchain, LLM with RAG. How to show source of retrieval and memory management?
Using Python and the LangChain libraries, I'm able to either "memorize" previous messages (use content of previous conversation turns as context) or show the source used to generate an answer from the vector store. But I can not manage to combine them... How would you do it?
Memory management
The code used for the memory management is the following:
system_prompt = (
            "You are an assistant for question-answering tasks. "
            "Use the following pieces of retrieved context to answer "
            "the question. If you don't know the answer, say that you "
            "don't know. Use three sentences maximum and keep the "
            "answer concise."

            "\n\n"
            "{context}"
        )

        contextualize_q_system_prompt = (
            "Given a chat history and the latest user question "
            "which might reference context in the chat history, "
            "formulate a standalone question which can be understood "
            "without the chat history. Do NOT answer the question, "
            "just reformulate it if needed and otherwise return it as is."
        )

        contextualize_q_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
            [
                ("system", contextualize_q_system_prompt),
                MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
                ("human", "{input}"),
            ]
        )
        history_aware_retriever = create_history_aware_retriever(
            self.llm, self.retriever, contextualize_q_prompt
        )

        # print((history_aware_retriever))

        qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
            [
                ("system", system_prompt),
                MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
                ("human", "{input}"),
            ]
        )

        question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(self.llm, qa_prompt)

        rag_chain = create_retrieval_chain(history_aware_retriever, question_answer_chain)

Showing resources
The code used for showing the resources is the following:
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
            "Summarize the main themes in these retrieved docs: {docs}."
        )

        # At the end of your answer provide the files path you used as sources to generate your answer.
        RAG_TEMPLATE = """
        You are an assistant for question-answering tasks. Use the following pieces of retrieved context to answer the question. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know. Use three sentences maximum and keep the answer concise.
        At the end of your answer provide the pages number you used as sources to generate your answer.
        <context>
        {context}
        </context>

        Answer the following question:

        {question}"""

        rag_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(RAG_TEMPLATE)

        def format_docs(docs):
            # return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)
            # return "\n\n".join(f"From {doc.metadata['source']}:\n{doc.page_content}" for doc in docs)
            return "\n\n".join(f"From {doc.metadata['page_number'] + 1}:\n{doc.page_content}" for doc in docs)

        chain = (
                RunnablePassthrough.assign(context=lambda input: format_docs(input["context"]))
                | rag_prompt
                | self.llm
                | StrOutputParser()
        )

        docs = self.vectorstore.similarity_search(question)

        answer = chain.invoke({"context": docs, "question": question})

I tried to combine the different chains but unsuccessfully. My intuition would be to make a custom chain that mimic:
create_history_aware_retriever

or to find a way to modify the retriever.
